# How to test if areas overlap (Python)

Tags: python, pygame, area, rectangles, ellipse

I'm a novice coder writing a Python program to simulate natural selection using the Pygame library.

One of the things I'm trying to accomplish is to make moving elliptical (or if this is too complex, rectangular) objects that overlap produce a child object that inherits their traits.

My problem is that I'm unable to create a working code to identify when any two object areas are overlapped. I need the code to identify when two objects are crossing paths (and momentarily overlapped) so that the game knows to spawn another shape.

At one point I tried a complex nested for-loop that I thought would work, but that caused the simulation to crash.

This is my code as is:

```
import pygame, random

# Define some colors
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

pygame.init()

# Set the width and height of the screen
map_width = 800
map_height = 800
size = [map_width, map_height]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

# Display name
pygame.display.set_caption("Natural Selection Game")

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# -------- Organism -----------
class Organism:

    def __init__(self):
        # Speed and direction
        self.change_x = random.randrange(0,6)
        self.change_y = random.randrange(0,6)

        # Dimensions
        self.width = random.randrange(5,50)
        self.height = random.randrange(5,50)

        # Diet (WIP)
        self.color = random.choice([red, green, blue])

        # Starting position
        self.x = random.randrange(0 + self.width, 800 - self.width)
        self.y = random.randrange(0 + self.height, 800 - self.height)

    # Spawn
    def spawn(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, self.color, [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height])

    # Initiate movement
    def move(self):
        self.x += self.change_x
        self.y += self.change_y

    # Bounce 
    def bounce(self, map_width, map_height):
        if self.x < 0 or self.x > map_width - self.width:
            self.change_x = self.change_x * -1
        if self.y < 0 or self.y > map_height - self.height:
            self.change_y = self.change_y * -1

# Initial spawning conditions
org_list = []
org_number = 15

for i in range(0,org_number):
    org = Organism()
    org_list.append(org)

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # ---- Event Processing ----
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # ---- Logic ----
    # Movement
    for i in org_list:
        i.move()
        i.bounce(map_width, map_height)

    # Reproduction

    # ---- Drawing ----
    # Set the screen background
    screen.fill(white)

    # Spawn organisms
    for i in org_list:
        i.spawn(screen)

    # --- Wrap-up
    # Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

# Close everything down
pygame.quit()
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be nice if you could MSPaint or something an example of what you're looking for. I think I understand, but I'm not *sure*

Comment: Can your shapes rotate or do they have a fixed orientation?

Comment: You didn't post the code that makes the simulation crash, did you? (I see no nested for loops).

Comment: The shapes do not rotate, they are fixed orientation but move about the screen. I got rid of the nested for loops awhile ago, before I even thought of asking for help, because I figured it was pointless.

Comment: This is exactly what the Pygame Rect class is for: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect

Comment: I stumbled upon that myself earlier. But that, too, was useless to me because the site doesn't sufficiently explain how to use it and my coding knowledge isn't sufficiently advanced to understand the examples. Would you mind explaining how I could use that in the context of my code?

Answer (score 3):

You should use [pygame.Rect](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) to keep position and size and then you can use Pygame functions to check collisions.

```
one_rect.colliderect(second_rect)

one_rect.coolidepoint(mouse_position)
```

See other functions in docs for [pygame.Rect](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

---

Pygame has also [pygame.sprite.Group](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) to keep group of sprites and check collisions for all sprites.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that giving your organism a `self.id = random.randomrange(11111,99999)` might help in identifying whether two organisms are the same or just at the same location with the same dimesnions - tho perhaps there is a unique property that can be accessed of the organism objects and you probably want a deterministic id generation method so there is no possibility of unintentional equality.

You need to either build a spawn function that takes two organisms or implement your spawn method on your organism object so that it can take as a parameter the spawn partner and in so doing can access the properties of each and mix them together and create the progeny. So I'm assuming that `OrganismA.spawn(OrganismB)` will create a progeny of OrganismA-B spawn.

You can see the overlap logic below. If the following four logical expressions are valid then the two boxes overlap. The math for the ellipse would be different but you could use a rectangular approximation for your ellipse if you'd like. We'll start with A and B as organism objects and define their min and max x and y. So minXB means the minimum x coord for b.

```
maxXB = B.x - B.width/2
maxXA = A.x - A.width/2
minYB = B.y - B.height/2
...etc.. below are the equalites that hold for overlapping boxes
maxXB > minXA
maxYB > minYA
maxYA > minYB
maxXA > minXA
```

I suggest you bin the organisms by some division of the map for efficiency. Example quadrants, where every organism in the 0-400 width 0-400 height is in quadrant 'I', etc. From there you will have better performance when you do something like the following.

```
def quadrant(Organism):
    if (Organism.x < 400 and Organism.y < 400):
        return 'III'
    elif (...

def spawnOrganisms():
    # create org_subLists for each quadrant
    org_subLists = { 'I': [], 'II': [], 'III': [], 'IV': [] }
    for i in org_list:
        org_quadrant = quadrant(i)
        org_subLists[org_quadrant].append(i)

    for quad in org_subLists:
        # only spawn progeny for lowerID to higerID parir to prevent A-B and B-A from each spawning the same/a similar org and avoid spawining an A-A spawn
        for orgA in org_subLists[quad]:
            for orgB in org_subLists[quad]:
                if (orgA.id < orgB.id):
                    if(maxXB > minXA and maxYB > minYA and maxYA > minYB and maxXA > minXA):
                        orgA.spawn(orgB)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use pygame's [`Sprite`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) class for your, well, sprites, since it makes your whole application easier to manage.

We don't need `spawn`, `move` and `bounce`, we simply use a single function [`update`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.update), which will [be called](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) by a [`Group`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group), which in turn we use instead of a simple list to hold our objects.

Each Sprite has it's own image, on which we draw a ellipsis. Then we create a [`Mask`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask) to [do pixel perfect collision](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask).

Here's a full, running example. Note that I replaced all your comments with my own, explaining what's going on:

```
import pygame, random

pygame.init()

map_width = 800
map_height = 800
size = [map_width, map_height]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

# pygame already defines a lot of colors, we we just use them
colors = pygame.color.THECOLORS
pygame.display.set_caption("Natural Selection Game")
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# just a simple generator to generate an id for each object 
def id_generator():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        yield i

ids = id_generator()

# just a helper function that wraps pygame.sprite.collide_mask
# to prevent a sprite from colliding with itself
def collide(a, b):
    if a.id == b.id:
        return False
    return pygame.sprite.collide_mask(a, b)

class Organism(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, id, org_list, color = None):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, org_list)
        self.org_list = org_list
        self.id = id
        # Speed and direction
        self.change_x = random.randrange(0,6)
        self.change_y = random.randrange(0,6)

        # Dimensions
        width = random.randrange(5,50)
        height = random.randrange(5,50)
        x = random.randrange(0 + width, map_width - width)
        y = random.randrange(0 + height, map_height - height)
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect(x, y, width, height)
        self.image = pygame.surface.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill(colors['hotpink2'])
        self.image.set_colorkey(colors['hotpink2'])

        # we either pass in the color, or create a random one
        self.color = color or random.choice([colors['red'], colors['green'], colors['blue']])
        pygame.draw.ellipse(self.image, self.color, [0, 0, width, height])
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)

        # we keep track of collisions currently happening
        # so we only spawn one children for each collisions  
        self.collisions = set()

        # just something to limit the number of organisms
        self.age = 0
        self.children = 0

    # Initiate movement
    def update(self):
        self.age += 1

        # we move by simply moving the rect
        # the Group's draw function will look that the rect attribute 
        # to determine the position for drawing the image 
        self.rect.move_ip(self.change_x, self.change_y)

        # we can make use of a lot of Rect's attributes to make 
        # this computation simpler
        if self.rect.left < 0 or self.rect.right > map_width:
            self.change_x *= -1

        if self.rect.top < 0 or self.rect.bottom > map_height:
            self.change_y *= -1

        # only reproduce if we are at least 200 ticks old
        # so newly created organisms spwan new ones at the
        # very moment they spawned themself
        if self.age < 200:
            return

        # just a narbitary limit so the screen does not get too full
        if self.age > 500:
            print str(self.id) + ' died of age'

            # kill() removes the Sprite from all its Groups (which is only org_list at the moment)
            self.kill()
            return

        # just an arbitary limit so the screen does not get too full 
        if self.children > 4:
            print str(self.id) + ' died of too many children'
            self.kill()
            return

        # check if we collided with another Sprite
        collided = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, self.org_list, collide)

        # also check if this 
        # - is a new collision
        # - the other organism is at least 200 ticks old
        # - there are not too many organisms at the screen at the moment
        if collided and not collided.id in self.collisions and collided.age > 200 and len(self.org_list) < 100:

            # keep track of the current collision, so this code is not triggerd 
            # every frame while the colliding organisms move other each other
            self.collisions.add(collided.id)
            collided.collisions.add(self.id)
            print str(self.id) + ' collided with ' + str(collided.id)

            # we create a new color out of the colors of the parents
            r, g, b = (self.color[0] + collided.color[0]) / 2, \
                      (self.color[1] + collided.color[1]) / 2, \
                      (self.color[2] + collided.color[2]) / 2
            color = [r, g, b]

            # let the color mutate sometimes for fun
            if random.randrange(0, 100) < 10:
                color[random.randrange(0, 3)] = random.randrange(0, 256)
                print 'Offspring of ' + str(self.id) + ' and ' + str(collided.id) + ' mutates'

            # create the new child with the new color
            Organism(next(ids), self.org_list, map(int, color))
            self.children += 1
            collided.children += 1
        else:
            # if there are currently no collisions, we clear the collisions set
            # so new collisions can happen
            self.collisions = set()

# we use a Group for all the draw/update/collision magic
org_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

for _ in range(15):
    Organism(next(ids), org_list)

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # we just call update on the group so update is called
    # an every sprite in the group
    org_list.update()

    screen.fill(colors['white'])

    # same for drawing: just call draw on the group
    org_list.draw(screen)

    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

I set some arbitary limits on how much objects are on the screen at once. If you want to speed up the collision detection, either skip the pixel perfect collision detection and use a rect or [circle](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_circle) based one. But the biggest improvement would probably be using a quadtree collision detection algorithm (but that is out of scope of this answer; just google it).

Comment: Thanks! I tried updating it to work with Python 3. I consistently get an error message reading 'invalid color argument' for lines 129 and 54 as soon as the first objects collide, however.

Comment: @ChristopherCostello Yeah, because, in Python 3, `map` does not return a list, but an iterator. Just wrap it in a list call, like `Organism(next(ids), self.org_list, list(map(int, color)))`

Answer (score 0):

Now, shapely package and its geometry provide all the geometires and related methods such as overlap, cross, intersect, intersection area and etc...
No need to write your own code.