# PyGame simulation will not render

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a natural selection simulator. I've asked a question pertaining to it before ([How to test if areas overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003640/how-to-test-if-areas-overlap-python)). Now I have a version of the code that I'd like to run but it does not. Instead of getting an error message, however, the window opens, but the simulation (that otherwise seems to me as though it should run) does not run.

It would seem to me that the problem has something to do with the initial spawn information not being passed into the main class for my organisms, but I can't be sure.

If anyone could identify why the code isn't working and tell me what I'd need to correct I'd really appreciate it.

## UPDATE

The command line returns information that the code is running, so the problem must be that the display isn't working. It definitely has to do with my sprites because removing

```
self.image.fill(colors['hotpink2'])
self.image.set_colorkey(colors['hotpink2'])
self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
```

from the **init** causes the rectangles to display briefly.

The updated code is as follows:

```
# Import libraries
import pygame, random, numpy

# Initialize PyGame
pygame.init()

# Define colors
colors = pygame.color.THECOLORS

# Set window dimensions
mapWidth = 800
mapHeight = 800
size = [mapWidth, mapHeight]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

# Display program title in window
pygame.display.set_caption("Natural Selection Game")

# Loop until user closes window
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Generate IDs for organisms
def id_generator():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        yield i

ids = id_generator()

# Prevent organisms from colliding with self
def collide(a, b):
    if a.id == b.id:
        return False
    return pygame.sprite.collide_mask(a, b)

# ----- Organisms -----
class Organism(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, width, height, x, y, changeX, changeY, lifespan, species):
        # Make PyGame Sprite
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, organisms)

        self.id = next(ids)

        # Set dimensions
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        # Set starting point
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        # Set motion type
        self.changeX = changeX
        self.changeY = changeY

        # Set lifespan
        self.lifespan = lifespan

        # Set species
        self.species = species
        if species == 'paper':
            self.color = colors['red']
        elif species == 'rock':
            self.color = colors['green']
        elif species == 'scissors':
            self.color = colors['blue']

        # Set age at birth
        self.age = 0

        # Recognize collisions as to produce only one offspring
        self.colliding = set()

        # Sprite body
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect(x, y, width, height)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill(colors['hotpink2'])
        self.image.set_colorkey(colors['hotpink2'])

        # Draw
        pygame.draw.ellipse(self.image, self.color, [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height])
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)

    # Randomly generate traits for first generation
    @classmethod
    def initialSpawn(cls):
        # Set dimensions for first generation
        width = random.randrange(5,50)
        height = random.randrange(5,50)

        # Set starting point for first generation
        x = random.randrange(0 + width, 800 - width)
        y = random.randrange(0 + height, 800 - height)

        # Set motion type for first generation
        changeX = random.randrange(0,6)
        changeY = random.randrange(0,6)

        # Set lifespan for first generation
        lifespan = random.randrange(300,700)

        # Set species for first generation
        species = random.choice(['paper', 'rock', 'scissors'])

        return cls(width, height, x, y, changeX, changeY, lifespan, species)

    # Inherit and/or mutate traits for offspring
    def reproduce(self, collidee):
        # Set dimensions for offspring
        width = random.choice(self.width, collidee.height)
        height = random.choice(self.width, collidee.height)

        # Set starting points for offspring
        x = random.choice(self.x, collidee.x)
        y = random.choice(self.y, collidee.y)

        # Set motion type for offspring
        changeX = random.choice(self.changeX, collidee.changeX)
        changeY = random.choice(self.changeY, collidee.changeY)

        # Set lifespan for offspring
        lifespan = numpy.mean(self.lifespan, collidee.lifespan)

        # Set species for offspring
        species = self.species

        return width, height, x, y, changeX, changeY, species

    def update(self):
        # Update age
        self.age += 1

        # Update movement
        self.rect.move_ip(self.changeX, self.changeY)

        # Manage bouncing
        if self.rect.left < 0 or self.rect.right > mapWidth:
            self.changeX *= -1
        if self.rect.top < 0 or self.rect.bottom > mapHeight:
            self.changeY *= -1

        # Death from aging
        if self.age > self.lifespan:
            print (self.id, ' died of age')
            self.kill()
            return

        # Check if collided with another organism of same species for mating or predation
        collidee = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, organisms, collide)

        # Check the prerequisites for mating:
        # - Not already colliding
        # - Same species
        # - No overpopulation
        if collidee and not collidee.id in self.colliding and self.species == collidee.species and len(self.organisms) < 100:

            # Keep track of the current collision, so this code is not triggerd throughout duration of collision
            self.colliding.add(collidee.id)
            collidee.colliding.add(self.id)
            print (self.id, ' mated with ', collidee.id)

            # The fun part! ;)
            self.reproduce(collidee)

        # Check the prerequisites for predation:
        # - Not already colliding
        # - Different species
        elif collidee and not collidee.id in self.colliding and self.species != collidee.species:
            if self.species == 'paper' and collidee.species == 'rock':
                collidee.kill()
                self.lifespan += 100
            elif self.species == 'rock' and collidee.species == 'scissors':
                collidee.kill()
                self.lifespan += 100
            elif self.species == 'scissors' and collidee.species == 'paper':
                collidee.kill()
                self.lifespan += 100
        else:
            # Organism is single and ready to mingle
            self.colliding = set()

# Organism group
organisms = pygame.sprite.Group()

# Initial spawner
for i in range(15):
    organisms.add(Organism.initialSpawn())

# ----- Simulation -----
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # Logic
    organisms.update()

    # Draw screen
    screen.fill(colors['white'])

    # Draw organisms
    organisms.draw(screen)

    # FPS
    clock.tick(60)

    # Update drawings
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling a class method `Organism.initialSpawn()` which returns `width, height, x, y, changeX, changeY, lifespan, species` but you don't do anything with it. It just goes directly to garbage collection.

You're probably trying to create a new organism from the variables you're given, and add those in the `pygame.sprite.Group`. This can be done like this:

```
# Organism group
organisms = pygame.sprite.Group()

# Initial spawner
for i in range(15):
    temp = Organims(*Organism.initialSpawn())
    organisms.add(temp)
```

Although, your `initialSpawn()` method has the wrong syntax. All methods in a class needs `self` as first parameter unless something else is specified. I would make it a class method and instead of returning a bunch of variables that you use to create a new Organism, you just return a new Organism directly.

```
class Organism(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # Randomly generate traits for first generation
    @classmethod
    def initialSpawn(cls):
        # Set dimensions for first generation
        width = random.randrange(5,50)
        height = random.randrange(5,50)

        # Set starting point for first generation
        x = random.randrange(0 + width, 800 - width)
        y = random.randrange(0 + height, 800 - height)

        # Set motion type for first generation
        changeX = random.randrange(0,6)
        changeY = random.randrange(0,6)

        # Set lifespan for first generation
        lifespan = random.randrange(300,700)

        # Set species for first generation
        species = random.choice(['paper', 'rock', 'scissors'])
        if species == 'paper':
            color = colors['red']
        elif species == 'rock':
            color = colors['green']
        elif species == 'scissors':
            color = colors['blue']

        return cls(width, height, x, y, changeX, changeY, lifespan, species)


# Organism group
organisms = pygame.sprite.Group()

# Initial spawner
for i in range(15):
    organisms.add(Organism.initialSpawn())
```

**EDIT:** Okay, I looked closer on your code and you have lots of errors.

1. Need to put `self` in your `__init__` method as first parameter.
2. In `__init__`, you have an unidentified function `add(organisms)`. Remove that.
3. In `__init__`, you're creating a `color` variable based on a condition but you don't use it. Instead you're trying to use an attribute `self.color` which you don't have. Change the variables `color` to attributes `self.color`.
4. In `__init__`, you're trying to access the class Surface by typing `pygame.surface.Surface`. There's no module `surface` and the class is in the pygame module. Just type `pygame.Surface` instead.
5. Add a decorator `@classmethod` and `cls` for `InitialSpawn` as I did above.
6. In `InitialSpawn`, remove the if-statements where you set color, because you don't need it. It's just unnecessary code.
7. In `update`, change `self.change_x` and `self.change_y` to `self.changeX` and `self.changeY` in `reproduce` metod. Be consistent.
8. In `update`, change `self.organisms` to just `organisms`. It's a global variable and not an attribute.
9. In `update`, `mate` is an undefined variable. Don't know what you're trying to do so I don't know how to fix that.

Those were the errors I found just using Pycharm. Change to an IDE that can detect errors (like Pycharm) when coding and it'll help you tremendously.

Comment: Thanks very much! It still doesn't run, however.

Comment: As I said, you had very many errors and I most likely didn't catch them all. Download [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows) (community version is free) or any other IDE that detects simple errors, so you can easily identify code with wrong syntax. Also, look up tutorials about classes since much of your code revolves around mistakes as whether an variable is a local variable or an attribute. There are simply to much errors for me to help you get it running properly.

Comment: To answer you're updated question, They're not showing because you fill them with the color  `colors['hotpink2']` and then set a colorkey for that color. It makes them transparent. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pygame/7079/drawing-on-the-screen/23788/transparency#t=201612111755139138907