# How to place these images of ships?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm a beginner in Python. How can I place these objects in the dictionary self.x on the second half of window.
Here is some of my code:

```
win_w = int(input("Enter the number of pixels corresponding to the width of the game window: "))
win_h = int(input("Enter the number of pixels corresponding to the height of the game window: "))
win = pygame.display.set_mode((win_w, win_h))
centre_of_win = win_w * 0.5

ships = ['ship1.png', 'ship2.png', 'ship3.png']

class Enemy_Ships:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = {'ship1.png': 50, 'ship2.png': 75, 'ship3.png': 100}
        self.y = 25
        self.xmax = random.uniform(centre_of_win, win_w)
        self.ymax = random.randint(0, win_h)
        self.color = (0, 100, 100)

    def drawing_enemy(self, ships):
        for element in ships:
            rect = pygame.Rect(self.xmax, self.ymax, 50, 25)
            pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, rect, 1, win_w)

enemy = Enemy Ships()

Enemy_Ships.drawing_enemy(ships)
pygame.display.update()
```

I want to place these images randomly between `centre_of_win` and win w (max width)

Answer (score 2):

To place the ships, the RNG should be placed inside the for loop of the drawing_enemy method (else, only a single random position would be created).

Additionally, for each placed ship a check is implemented to see [whether it collides](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41017444/9501624) with previously placed ships.

```py
import random
import pygame
from pygame import KEYDOWN, K_ESCAPE, QUIT

pygame.init()

win_w, win_h = 800, 500

win = pygame.display.set_mode((win_w, win_h))
centre_of_win = win_w * 0.5

ships = ["ship1.png", "ship2.png", "ship3.png"]


class Enemy_Ships:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = {"ship1.png": 50, "ship2.png": 75, "ship3.png": 100}
        self.y = 25
        self.color = (0, 100, 100)

    def drawing_enemy(self, ships):
        placed_ships = []
        for ship in ships:
            # get ship width from self.x dictionary
            width = self.x[ship]
            # define random numbers for each ship individually,
            # repeat if ships would collide
            is_colliding = True
            while is_colliding:
                x = random.uniform(centre_of_win, win_w - width)
                y = random.randint(0, win_h)
                # generate ship, check collision with placed ships
                rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, self.y)
                is_colliding = any(
                    rect.colliderect(previous_ship) for previous_ship in placed_ships
                )
            placed_ships.append(rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, rect, 1, win_w)


enemy = Enemy_Ships()

enemy.drawing_enemy(ships)
pygame.display.update()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            running = False
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
```

[image]

Remark on design:

Overall, the purpose of the `Enemy_Ships` class is not entirely "clean". It defines widths and images of ships, but when drawing them, the access to the generated rectangles is lost. I would propose to only implement an `EnemyShip` class, which then is instantiated with a simple function and then drawn.

Lastly, instead of working with strings for ship-identifies such as `ship1.png`, I would use [Enums](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html), which prevents errors due to Typos:

```py
import random
from enum import Enum

import pygame
from pygame import KEYDOWN, K_ESCAPE, QUIT

pygame.init()

win_w, win_h = 800, 500

win = pygame.display.set_mode((win_w, win_h))
centre_of_win = win_w * 0.5


class EnemyShip:
    def __init__(
        self, x: int, y: int, width: int, height: int, color: tuple[int] = (0, 100, 100)
    ):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
        self.color = color


class ShipType(Enum):
    SMALL = 50
    MID = 75
    BIG = 100


def create_enemies(ship_types: list[ShipType], height: int = 25) -> list[EnemyShip]:
    placed_ships = []
    for ship in ship_types:
        width = ship.value
        is_colliding = True
        while is_colliding:
            x = int(random.uniform(centre_of_win, win_w - width))
            y = random.randint(0, win_h)
            # generate ship, check collision with placed ships
            enemy = EnemyShip(x, y, width, height)
            is_colliding = any(
                enemy.rect.colliderect(previous_ship.rect)
                for previous_ship in placed_ships
            )
        placed_ships.append(enemy)
    return placed_ships


ships = [ShipType.SMALL, ShipType.MID, ShipType.BIG]

enemies = create_enemies(ships)
for enemy in enemies:
    pygame.draw.rect(win, enemy.color, enemy.rect, 1, win_w)
pygame.display.update()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            running = False
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run the project it turns out that the enemy ships can't be seen on the screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/axs41.png

I send more of the code:

```
win = pygame.display.set_mode((win_w, win_h))
centre_of_win = win_w * 0.5
ship_x = 0
ship_y = 0
lines_color = (0, 0, 0)
square_size = 25
users_ships= ['ship1.png', 'ship2.png', 'ship3.png']
area = pygame.Surface(win.get_size())
area.fill((63, 131, 171))

def drawing_grid():
    for ship_x in range(0, win_w, square_size):
        for ship_y in range(0, win_h, square_size):
        square = pygame.Rect(ship_x, ship_y, square_size, square_size)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, lines_color, square, 1)
        pygame.draw.line(win, lines_color, (centre_of_win, win_h[![enter image description here][1]][1]), (centre_of_win, 0), 6)

def loading_images(user_ships):
    return pygame.image.load(user_ships).convert()

# here is class EnemyShip, ShipType(Enum) and def create_enemies
# also lines with movement and rotation of the ship that work perfectly fine

loading_images(user_ships[0])
win.blit(area, (0, 0))
drawing_grid()
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: If you want to add details to your questions, in the future please [edit your original question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276268/9501624) instead of adding details as an answer.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could reduce the code to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. an example which can be directly executed without any modifications. Please try to get rid of images (ship<1,2,3>.png) and undefined variables (´okienko´), so that any one is able to execute the code directly.